# Use personal access token to view raw content of files in GitHub

Tags: github

How can I use personal access token to view raw content of files in GitHub? I tried to do it with token@raw..., username:token@raw... etc. but none of them worked.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I need to use the token in URL.

Comment: Are you using any particular language or framework, or just interested in HTTP usage?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio C#, I am trying to set up the auto update thing by ClickOnce and I saw a video for it. But it needs a public repository, but as I have my MySQL database info and some other secret things I can't make the repository public.

Answer (score 1):

This format (replacing the capitalized sections) should work:

```
https://TOKEN@raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPO/BRANCH/PATH
```

Note that this appears to block web browsers, you'd have to make a GET request from an HTTP client (like Insomnia) to test it. If this doesn't work in your plugin, please explain what happens, as it may be sending the wrong headers.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. I need to do it with URL, because Visual Studio doesn't supports get requests for ClickOnce (I think).

Comment: Please explain your ClickOnce configuration, and if possible, how it's making the request.

Comment: It needs to get the raw directory.

Comment: So it wants a root URL that it can append its own path to? If so, try `https://TOKEN@raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPO/BRANCH`.